# Count by grouping field value from firestore in angular

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire2

I have tried to get count of grouping similar values from firestore database in angular but didnot worked for me. Here initialised empty balance and balances arrays.
Please help me out to fix this issue.

Here is my working code:

```
this.db.collection('asset_master', ref => ref.orderBy('part_name')).valueChanges().subscribe(res => res.map(
  data => {// checking the value with arrary value
      if ( this.balances.some(check => check.part_name === data['part_name']) && this.balances.some(check => check.model_name === data['model_name']) && this.balances.some(check => check.manufacturer === data['manufacturer'])) { 
      // getting index value of matched value.
      let index = this.balances.findIndex(d => d.part_name === data['part_name']);
      console.log('in if condition index array value', this.balances[index].part_name);
      this.balances[index].count += 1;
    } else {
      console.log('in else condition value is',data['part_name']);
      this.balance = {'asset_type': data['asset_type'],'part_name': data['part_name'],'model_name': data['model_name'],'manufacturer':data['manufacturer'] ,'count': 1}
      this.balances.push(this.balance);
    }
  }
)
);
```

Firestore database structure is:

```
Collection:        Document:                  Collection:
assset_master      fhjhgjhggh65yt765ty7      asset_type: IT
                                             part_name: SMPS
                                             asset_type: IT
                                             part_name: HARDISK
                                             asset_type: IT
                                             part_name: SMPS
```

Required output should be:

```
     SMPS       2
     HARDISK    4
```

Comment: What's your actual output?

Comment: Actual output I got is 'Array[]'. i.e empty array.

Comment: Resolved it myself.Thank you.